# anmated.mesh is not working in react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-spring, react-three-drei

I tried to make meshes interact with on click using react-spring and when I build this onclick function I got this error

> type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at App.js:27.

and App.js code follows

```
import "./App.scss";
import { OrbitControls, Plane, softShadows, Sphere } from "@react-three/drei";
// import SpinningMesh from "./Box";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

import { MeshWobbleMaterial } from "@react-three/drei";
import { useSpring, a } from "react-spring";

// soft Shadows
softShadows();

const SpinningMesh = ({ position, color, speed, args }) => {
  //ref to target the mesh
  const mesh = useRef();

  //useFrame allows us to re-render/update rotation on each frame
  useFrame(() => (mesh.current.rotation.x = mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01));

  //Basic expand state
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
  // React spring expand animation
  const props = useSpring({
    scale: expand ? [1.4, 1.4, 1.4] : [1, 1, 1],
  });
  return (
    <a.mesh
      position={position}
      ref={mesh}
      onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)}
      scale={props.scale}
      castShadow
    >
      <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={args} />
      <MeshWobbleMaterial
        color={color}
        speed={speed}
        attach="material"
        factor={0.6}
      />
    </a.mesh>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {/* <Header /> */}
      {/* Our Scene & Camera is already built into our canvas */}
      <Canvas
        colorManagement
        shadowMap
        camera={{ position: [-5, 2, 10], fov: 60 }}
      >
        {/* This light makes things look pretty */}
        <ambientLight intensity={0.3} />
        {/* Our main source of light, also casting our shadow */}
        <directionalLight
          castShadow
          position={[0, 10, 0]}
          intensity={1.5}
          shadow-mapSize-width={1024}
          shadow-mapSize-height={1024}
          shadow-camera-far={50}
          shadow-camera-left={-10}
          shadow-camera-right={10}
          shadow-camera-top={10}
          shadow-camera-bottom={-10}
        />
        {/* A light to help illumnate the spinning boxes */}
        <pointLight position={[-10, 0, -20]} intensity={0.5} />
        <pointLight position={[0, -10, 0]} intensity={1.5} />
        <group>
          {/* This mesh is the plane (The floor) */}
          <mesh
            rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
            position={[0, -3, 0]}
            receiveShadow
          >
            <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[100, 100]} />
            <shadowMaterial attach="material" opacity={0.3} />
          </mesh>
          <SpinningMesh
            position={[0, 1, 0]}
            color="lightblue"
            args={[3, 2, 1]}
            speed={2}
          />
          <SpinningMesh position={[-2, 1, -5]} color="pink" speed={6} />
          <SpinningMesh position={[5, 1, -2]} color="pink" speed={6} />
        </group>
        {/* Allows us to move the canvas around for different prespectives */}
        <OrbitControls />
      </Canvas>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

can someone help me to solve this problem

Comment: That `<boxBufferGeometry>` looks suspicious. It's not imported anywhere in the code you posted, and also React component names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: @tromgy I called the box geometry that's the standard method to call in react-three-fiber

Answer (score 1):

found that react spring have changed have to install `npm install three @react-spring/three`  and it worked for me